# Optimize PostgreSQL query with levenshtein() function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I have a table with approximately 7 million records. The table has a first_name and last_name column which I want to search on using the levenshtein() distance function.

```sql
select levenshtein('JOHN', first_name) as fn_distance,
       levenshtein('DOE', last_name) as ln_distance,
       id,
       first_name as "firstName",
       last_name as "lastName"
  from person
 where first_name is not null
   and last_name is not null
   and levenshtein('JOHN', first_name) <= 2
   and levenshtein('DOE', last_name) <= 2
 order by 1, 2
 limit 50;
```

The above search is slow (4 - 5 secs), what can I do to improve performance? Should a create indexes on the two columns, or something else?

After I added indexes below:

```sql
create index first_name_idx on person using gin (first_name gin_trgm_ops);

create index last_name_idx on person using gin(last_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

The query now takes ~11 secs. :(

New query:

```sql
select similarity('JOHN', first_name) as fnsimilarity,
       similarity('DOW', last_name) as lnsimilarity,
       first_name as "firstName",
       last_name as "lastName",
       npi
  from person
 where first_name is not null
   and last_name is not null
   and similarity('JOHN', first_name) >= 0.2
   and similarity('DOW', last_name) >= 0.2
 order by 1 desc, 2 desc, npi
 limit 50;
```

Comment: The `levenstein()` function has two input string parameters, one may correspond to a column of the table `person`,  either `first_name` or `last_name`, the other one correspond to the value you want to calculate the distance against. This value is not a constant or a parameter known when the index is calculated at the insert or update events on the table `person`. So I don't see how you can use this function in an index.

Comment: You can consider the full text search capability instead, and which can rely on indexes, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/textsearch-intro.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in index type that supports levenshtein distances.  I'm not aware of any 3rd party index implementations to do so either.

Another string similarity measure, trigram similarity, does have an index method [to support it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html).  Maybe you can switch to using that measure instead.

You need to write the query using the % operator, not the similarity function.  So it would look something like this:

```
set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold TO 0.2;
select similarity('JOHN', first_name) as fnsimilarity,
       similarity('DOW', last_name) as lnsimilarity,
       first_name as "firstName",
       last_name as "lastName",
       npi
  from person
 where first_name is not null
   and last_name is not null
   and 'JOHN' % first_name
   and 'DOW' % last_name
 order by 1, 2, npi
 limit 50;
```

But note that 0.2 is very low cutoff, and the lower the cutoff the less efficient the index.