# best match sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigdata

I have a table (companies) in my postgresql database with more than 300,000 companies (adidas, goochie, samsung, ferrari, etc.).
The table itself contains only two columns: ID, company_name.

The user has a search for all companies. However, for example, the database stores the name of the company under the name "NIKE INC" and if the user enters the query "NIKE", then, accordingly, it remains without search results, although in fact this company is in the database.

I would like to write such a sql query that will find records in the database by the highest match. That is, for example, if the user enters "belhard", and the database has an entry "lls belhard company", so that the user would receive this result

I am sure that such tasks have already been solved, but I can not find examples. Perhaps you can share either links or code example

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE company_name like '%belhard%'` would be a starting point for this. `regexp` functionality may be a next step. [Fuzzy Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) algos would be even better, like Levenshtein Distance, or Jaro-Winkler, etc

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for paying attention to my question. The code you wrote covers, as you can imagine, very few cases. Something more serious is needed here.

Comment: Does Full Text search not satisfy your searching?

Comment: @Stu Thank you, I have not tried it, now I need to check it out

Comment: @Stu I understood what you mean. Unfortunately no, this method does not work. For example, the user enters the word "Volswagen" (without "k"), but the database has an entry "Volkswagen Group" and if you use Full Text search, the user will not get his result

Comment: That's where Fuzzy Matching would help. `Volswagen` would have a Levenshtein distance of "1", for instance, meaning only a single change had to happen to get from `Volswagen` to `Volkswagen`. Jaro-Winkler would give you similar results. Soundex, as another option (although it has more limited use cases) would recognize that "Volswagen" and "Volkswagen" are pronounced similarly and would return a high match likelyhood. Personally, I would concentrate my efforts on these different algorithms.

Comment: In your question examples you are looking for phrases or words, but not *misspelled* words; if that's *not* the requirement then yes, you will have to use some more complex fuzzy logic matching.

Comment: @Stu In the question, I gave one single example. Yes, the script should handle misspelled words too, for example: the user enters "Amason", but there is "Amazon" in the database, and this should be displayed to the user

Comment: I would agree that Levenshtein distance is what you need.

Comment: Use "Full Text Search". It's free and included in PostgreSQL for the same price.

Comment: @TheImpaler take a look please messages above

Comment: @Paul have you tried the pg_trgm extension used for determining the similarity of alphanumeric text based on trigram matching

Comment: @NnaemekaDanielJohn Yes, that's what I'm testing right now. But there is one nuance that it does not take into account the register. For example, if the user enters "TRUCKING", and there are two options for this company in the database (yes, these are my problems, but let's leave it) - "TRUCKING" and "Trucking", then why does this algorithm select "Trucking" in the first place. Perhaps you know how to take into account case here

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports a string similarity measure called "Trigram similarity" and it enables indexing to assist in this (unlike Levenstein distancing).

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES 
 ('Apple Inc.')
,('Apple Corp.')
,('Apple Incorporated')
,('Apple Corporation')
,('Apple')
,('Aple Inc.')
,('App Inc.')
,('Aple Corporation')
,('Appl Incorporated')
,('App Corporation')
,('Microsoft Inc.')
,('Microsoft Corp.')
,('Microsoft Incorporated')
,('Microsoft Corporation')
,('Microsoft')
,('Microsft Inc.')
,('Micro Inc.')
,('Microsft Corporation')
,('Micro Incorporated')
,('Micro Corporation')
```

;

Setup for "Trigram similarity":

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm; 

CREATE INDEX companies_name_gin ON companies USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Queries:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.3;
SELECT name 
FROM companies 
WHERE name % 'apple';
```

| name |
| --- |
| Apple Inc. |
| Apple Corp. |
| Apple Incorporated |
| Apple Corporation |
| Apple |
| Aple Inc. |

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.7;
SELECT name 
FROM companies 
WHERE name % 'apple';
```

| name |
| --- |
| Apple |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Am_9n3v9)

also see: [Optimize PostgreSQL query with levenshtein() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585279/optimize-postgresql-query-with-levenshtein-function)

```
INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES 
    ,('Volkswagon')
    ,('Vokswagon')
    ,('Volkswagen')
;

SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.3;
SELECT name 
FROM companies 
WHERE name % 'Volkswagon';
```

| name |
| --- |
| Volkswagon |
| Vokswagon |
| Volkswagen |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3cTSy11Z)